# Add codesandbox.io to the list of sites that prompt to put code in the question itself?

Tags: feature-request, code, quality-filter

As far as I am aware, if someone asks a question and pastes a link to websites like JSFiddle, JSBin, or CodePen, they get prompted to put code in the question itself.

Lately I've been seeing links to [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io) with no code in the question itself.

Should Stack Overflow automatically prompt for code for CodeSandbox links, like they do for similar websites?

Comment: Wouldn't mind seeing stackblitz and a few others added to the list, but codesandbox.io does seem to be the biggest offender.

Comment: Ah, I was just about to make a post on this - I am seeing an established user in the React tag repeatedly using CodeSandbox links without any code in the questions themselves. They've posted five since April, and are not responding to multiple messages to improve their behaviour, despite several question closures.

Comment: I would expect this is a trivial feature to implement - basically adding a domain into a list - but the request has languished for four years.